# Unaltered Test passes in Sandbox AND Production, but fails during unrelated deployment validation

Tags: apex, unit-test, managed-package, failing-tests

I am trying to deploy a few classes. I've got a Sandbox that I literally created this morning off of Production. Nothing is different between the two *except* the 3 classes I'm deploying.

How can it possibly happen that an unrelated Test in the org passes in BOTH environments pre-deploy, yet somehow magically fails during validation? Here's a debug snippet of the first occurrence of the exception:

```
17:22:03.392 (5395258016)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|CampaignTrigger on Campaign trigger event AfterUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/CampaignTrigger
17:22:03.399 (5399758426)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Workflow:Campaign
17:22:03.399 (5482111461)|METHOD_ENTRY|[56]||System.Test.stopTest()
17:22:03.497 (5497726340)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5498236120)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5498309414)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5498439134)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5506792563)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5506832290)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5506873375)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5506944995)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5507120013)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5507138315)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5507148965)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5507207035)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5507458722)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5507475887)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5507484078)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5507752219)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5507771400)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5507812433)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5507832516)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5507844364)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5507981794)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5508084692)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.497 (5572806434)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|cbit
17:22:03.399 (5776191483)|METHOD_EXIT|[56]||System.Test.stopTest()
17:22:03.399 (5776269192)|FATAL_ERROR|System.UnexpectedException: No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a test method.  Please make sure the iterable returned from your start method matches the batch size, resulting in one executeBatch invocation.

External entry point
17:22:03.399 (5776318677)|FATAL_ERROR|System.UnexpectedException: No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a test method.  Please make sure the iterable returned from your start method matches the batch size, resulting in one executeBatch invocation.
```

There is no call to executeBatch() in any of my code, so I can only deduce that it's the managed package. But even so, how can this even happen if the same test (unrelated to the code I'm otherwise deploying) passes in both the Sandbox and Production pre-deploy??

...this is clearly how I wanted to spend my Friday -_-

Comment: @sfdcfox It's my test, not theirs. It's triggering their code (evidently).

Comment: Are you using `@isTest(SeeAllData=true)` in any of your tests, or otherwise inserting/updating 201+ records?

Comment: @sfdcfox In this case, yes, because I have to... The test involves defaulting custom CampaignMemberStatus records, which are only visible to tests with that annotation.

Comment: @sfdcfox Again though, the test is identical in both orgs and passes in both. It only throws this exception during validation/deployment.

Comment: @sfdcfox I guess the more generic question though is - how is this even possible? Is there something occurring in deployment validation that doesn't happen when running a test normally within an org? How can this pass in both places, yet fail during deployment?

Comment: Are you deploying new trigger logic, or new logic in a trigger handler? New Process Builders or Flows? There's a number of reasons the test itself might fail despite being identical, but it comes down to a different code path somewhere.

Comment: There are possible failure modes that could happen during a deployment that don't occur with regular tests, but usually not of this nature. Do you have premier support? They could probably tell you more.

Comment: @sfdcfox I'm deploying changes to Test classes only, to fix other issues this same managed package was causing. EDIT mid comment - I removed the ad-hoc "fix" they had sent me to "disable" their code (involved sending a JSON object to some Controller class in their package) and I'm no longer getting the exception. That confirms it's their code. Ironically, it's the workaround code intended to fix another issue that's causing another problem...

Comment: It happens, unfortunately. Not all vendors are up to date on their tests as they should be. Hopefully this makes your Friday a bit better?

Comment: @sfdcfox Feelings are mixed, but at the very least, I can get the deploy done before Dreamforce AND I have the added bonus of not having to deal with Premier Support. So, overall win. (But this vendor is at two strikes with me)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit an older post now but for people having the same problem my solution might work. The reason my tests were passing in my sandbox as well as the full sandbox but were failing in production and during the deployment process was that I was impersonating a different user in the prod (a specific type of user we have in our org called the dev-user) and I was making deployment under that user. Once I logged in with my own user and ran deployment validation everything worked. Sorry if this is not an informative answer, it's just my experience dealing with this issue that might put someone in the right path to find the reason why they have the same issue.

Comment: definitely a valid possibility; normally, tests are run as sysad and within tests one uses `System.runAs(someMockedUser) {..}` if you are trying to test behavior with diff user permissions/CRUD/sharing